# Rails - How do I use a string to access an attribute of the same name, in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm templating an index page as a partial for the sake of DRY. 
A section of the :locals being passed into the partial are as follows:

```
:locals => { :data_set => @accounts # @accounts is set in the controller as @accounts = Account.find(:all)
             :attr_1 => "name" }
```

What I want to be able to do in the partial is along the lines of:

```
<% data_set.each do |d| %>
  <%= d.:attr_1 %>
<% end %>
```

My previous attempts have all ended up with "name" being printed instead of the contents of d.name which is what I want.

Is there a way to achieve that, or perhaps a better way of doing what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the key attr_1 with the value "name". It's always going to be name.

If the objects in data_set have an attribute called name, you don't need the second variable at all. You just need to do

```
<% data_set.each do |d| %>
  <%= d.name %>
<% end <%>
```

Otherwise, if you want to get screwy and really do want to pass name as a method call, because, say, you have several different kinds of objects in data set you could instead do

```
<%= d.send attr_1 %>
```

Which will send "name" to the object d.

Comment: Indeed, I needed to get screwy with this. Using d.send was what I needed, thanks =]